# How to increase the size of a partition that sits before an encrypted one?

Tags: lvm, luks

I have the following (lsblk output):
[image: http://i.imgur.com/tOTLghL.png]

And I want to increase the size of the boot partition (sdb2) but I'm not able to put unallocated space before the LVM partition (sb3), is there a way to do this? I found ways to increase the size of the LVM partition itself but nothing regarding putting that unallocated space before the partition so that it can be used to increase the size of another.

Comment: What's the difference between `/boot/efi` and `/boot`? I'm curious because on my (NixOS) system I have the ESP mounted at `/boot`. So maybe it would be possible to "merge" sdb1 and sdb2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope you can't move unallocated space around because the partition table reflects the location of sectors on the disk. Each sector has an ID from 1 to {a lot} and they are allocated in continuous blocks to partitions. Once allocated you can't easily move them around.

Is you `sdb4` in use or not? If not one thing you can do is to *create a new partition* `/boot` partition from `sdb4` and move the files here. It will require updating the boot loader, probably `grub2`, but it's reasonably easy to do.

However 238MB should be enough for `/boot` - if you're getting out of space warnings you may want to **delete old, unused kernel packages**. It is usually enough to keep only the running one and the one before in case you need to roll back.

How to delete them depends on your distribution, you apparently use *Fedora*, so here I found a link that should help:
https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/delete-remove-old-kernels-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: With three kernels it was too close for comfort. I deleted one now but it was around 180MiB. I updated it so that only two kernels are allowed to be installed at the same time but still would've liked to just increase the size of the partition. Anyways, the next best option is do what you suggested and just change the partition. Might do that in the future or just wait till I have to reinstall my main OS and increase the size of it there. Thanks!